# (Mini)USB keyboard has D- default high

Tags: usb, usb-device, keyboard

I have a keyboard from an old tablet case with a mini-USB connector that I want to read out using a PIC32 microcontroller.

When I apply 5V to the keyboard (completely standalone, no other circuitry around), the keyboard does do something on the data lines when I press some keys, but it doesn't seem to be using the [protocol I know](https://www.networktechinc.com/usb-prots.html):

[image]

Here, D+ and D- seem to be each other's inverse most of the time, and D- is low when idle. My keyboard doesn't show the same pattern.

D- is high when idle. D+ is also high when idle, I didn't just swap the lines. I don't have the tools to perform in-depth analysis, but I do know the two lines are not simply the same.

Are there USB keyboards that have a different protocol (for example, D- inverted, or something entirely different)? What could be going on here?

Answer (score 3):

A lot of keyboards support PS/2 for backwards compatibility - they detect whether connected to a USB host, and if not will behave as a PS/2 keyboard.

It is possible this is what you are seeing - if you haven't connected anything to the D+/D- lines then the keyboard would determine it is not connected to a USB host and fall back to PS/2. If it didn't have this mode, you would probably see nothing at all on the data lines as there is no host connected to issue commands.

There are USB to PS/2 adapters which are basically just passive and connect the D+ and D- signals to the clock and data signals of the PS/2 connector. Might be worth trying one of these (if you have one lying around and a computer which has as PS/2 port) to verify.

Comment: Okay, that's very interesting, thanks. Also when I connect it to the PIC it doesn't work, so that could mean the PIC is doing something wrong. Do you happen to know what I should see on the host lines if it is 'listening'? I.e., what would the keyboard check for to see if it's talking to a USB or PS/2 host?

Comment: @CamilStaps Have a look at page 11 of this [datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/ref_manual/DRM014.pdf). It's for a keyboard controller which supports dual mode. Page 11 shows a flow chart of how it does the detection, so it's possible yours might do something similar. There's an explanation on the next page

Comment: Great, thanks. I didn't figure it out yet, if I follow that flowchart in my situation I would detect a USB host. But it's certainly helpful, I have a new direction to search in.